# Linux command to find files changed in the last n seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I would like a Linux command to find files changed in the last `n` seconds.

Is there a shell script or other tool that I can run from command line interface or GUI?

Answer (score 18):

[The solution with mtime specifying seconds](https://superuser.com/users/72260/anubhava) doesn't work on my linux systems that use `find --version` == `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`.

I get the following error:

```
mycomputer:~/new$ find . -mtime -60s
find: missing argument to `-mtime'
mycomputer:~/new$ find . -mtime -60seconds
find: missing argument to `-mtime'
```

However, I can use `-mmin` (for modified in the last m minutes), and can it can take in a decimal argument; e.g., the following finds files modified in the last 30 seconds.

```
find . -mmin 0.5
```

So for example; creating files last modified 1s, 6s, 11s, ... ago for the past 120 seconds, this command finds:

```
mycomputer:~/new$ for i in $(seq 1 5 120); do touch -d "-$i seconds" last_modified_${i}_seconds_ago ; done
mycomputer:~/new$ find . -mmin 0.5
.
./last_modified_1_seconds_ago
./last_modified_26_seconds_ago
./last_modified_11_seconds_ago
./last_modified_16_seconds_ago
./last_modified_21_seconds_ago
./last_modified_6_seconds_ago
```

So if you really need it in seconds you can do something like:

```
localhost:~/new$ for i in $(seq 1 1 120); do touch -d "-$i seconds" last_modified_${i}_seconds_ago ; done
localhost:~/new$ N=18; find . -mmin $(echo "$N/60"|bc -l)
./last_modified_1_seconds_ago
./last_modified_9_seconds_ago
./last_modified_14_seconds_ago
./last_modified_4_seconds_ago
./last_modified_12_seconds_ago
./last_modified_13_seconds_ago
./last_modified_8_seconds_ago
./last_modified_3_seconds_ago
./last_modified_5_seconds_ago
./last_modified_11_seconds_ago
./last_modified_17_seconds_ago
./last_modified_16_seconds_ago
./last_modified_7_seconds_ago
./last_modified_15_seconds_ago
./last_modified_10_seconds_ago
./last_modified_6_seconds_ago
./last_modified_2_seconds_ago
```

Answer (score 14):

Use find command like this:

> `find . -name "*.txt" -mtime -60s`

To find all `*.txt` files modified in last 60 seconds.

Comment: In linux, using find (from GNU findutils 4.4.2), I get an error with this command: `find: missing argument to \`-mtime'`.  However, I can get the desired behavior using -mmin and a decimal argument.  I could not find any reference in the manpage for find for using `s` as an argument.

Comment: -60s isn't a valid argument to `-mtime`.  Nor is "60s" even a valid option in POSIX or GNU find.  The argument to `-mtime` is a number which specifies the number of 24-hour periods ago when a file was modified.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -newermt '6 seconds ago'
```

The `-mtime -60s` option, mentioned in an answer, doesn't work on many versions of `find`, even in 2016. `-newermt` is a much better option to us. It can parse many different date and time formats.

An alternative method using `mmin` is this:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -mmin -0.5

# Finds files modified within the last 0.5 minute, i.e. last 30 seconds
```

This option might not work for all `find` versions.

Comment: This is clearly the best solution.

Answer (score 10):

Similar to what glenn suggested, if you want to find everything modified, say, in the time during which an installer process was running, it might be easier to do something like:

```
touch /tmp/checkpoint
<do installer stuff>
find / -newer /tmp/checkpoint
```

Then you don't have to do the time calculation; you just find things changed after the checkpoint file.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a version of find that doesn't support `-mtime -60s` then a better solution is

```
touch -d '-60 seconds' /tmp/newerthan
find . -name "*.txt" -newer /tmp/newerthan
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're monitoring a directory for changes to files, you probably want to use [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) instead of some infinite polling loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your  version of `find` does not accept seconds or real values, just like mine, use `-mmin`, but specify 0, and you'll get all files modified in less than a minute:

```
$ touch test; find . -type f -mmin 0
./test
```